# localStorage on javascript leads refreshing

Tags: javascript, local-storage, logout, idle-timer

I am trying to fire out the user when idle, using javascript across tabs, the below code working fine for single tab for multiple tab it is not working properly

For Eg: I have set 10 secs as idle time and left the first tab it throws out the user on 10 seconds, assume i opened the first tab at **00:00:05** hours and opened second tab at **00:00:10** hours and working on second tab for **00:00:13** hours and left both the tabs the project have to logout on **00:00:23** right? but it logs out on **00:00:15**, I don't know whats happening right here, if it was not refreshing properly how could it stay on second tab for a long time when i am using it? if it is refreshing properly how could it log me out based on first opened tab, and the code as follows.

```
<script>
var IDLE_TIMEOUT = 10; //seconds
localStorage.setItem("setTimeOut", "0");

document.onclick = function () {    
    localStorage.setItem("setTimeOut", "0");
};

document.onmousemove = function () {   
    localStorage.setItem("setTimeOut", "0");
};

document.onkeypress = function () {  
    localStorage.setItem("setTimeOut", "0");
};

document.onfocus = function () {  
    localStorage.setItem("setTimeOut", "0");
};


window.setInterval(CheckIdleTime, 1000);
function CheckIdleTime() {  
    localStorage.setItem("setTimeOut", parseInt(localStorage.getItem("setTimeOut"))+1);
    if (localStorage.getItem("setTimeOut") >= IDLE_TIMEOUT) {
        alert('Times up!, You are idle for about 15 minutes, Please login to continue');
        document.location.href = "logout.php";
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: hey did you got solution ? ...if yes please post function script here ...as i am in need too for same ...thanks

Comment: Sorry for the delay, the below solution works for me, which i was marked correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of incrementing the value each second on each tab, which means every second it will be increased with the number of tabs open rather than 1 second, simply set the current time on interaction and then compare to that every second.

So, in your event handlers, do this instead:

```
localStorage.setItem("lastInteraction", Date.now())
```

... and then in your `CheckIdleTime()` function, remove the `localStorage.setItem()` and change your `if` condition to this:

```
Number(localStorage.getItem("lastInteraction")) + (IDLE_TIMEOUT * 1000) < Date.now()
```

The condition takes the time when the last interaction occurred, adds the timeout constant and then checks if the current time (now) has passed that value.

Answer (score 1):

This line will run every second for each instance of your app (tab). That means that if you have 2 tabs open, then its incrementing by 2 every second instead of 1.

```
localStorage.setItem("setTimeOut", parseInt(localStorage.getItem("setTimeOut"))+1);
```

You can fix this by using a specific time when the user will be logged out, rather than a countdown.